# Return Objects (PHP Best Practices)

Tags: php, oop

When writing PHP OOP code, is it a good / acceptable / wise practice to use "return objects" for your various classes in order to pass along success, failure, error messages, etc. up the food chain?

Example of what I have now:

**"Return object":**

```
class JsqlReturn{
    public $response;
    public $success;
    public $debug_message;
    public $mysqli_result_obj;
    function __construct($bool=false,$debug_message=NULL,$res=NULL,$mysqli_result_obj=NULL){
        $this->success = $bool;
        $this->response = $res;
        $this->debug_message = $debug_message;
        $this->mysqli_result_obj = $mysqli_result_obj;
    }
}
```

**Main Class with sample method:**

```
class Jsql{

    function connect($host,$username,$password,$database){ #protected?
        $this->db = new \mysqli($host,$username,$password,$database);
        if($this->db->connect_errno){
            return new JsqlReturn(false,"Connection failed: (".$this->db->connect_errno.") ".$this->db->connect_error);
        }
        else{
            return new JsqlReturn(true,NULL,"Connection success.");
        }
    }

}
```

**Implementation:**

```
$db = new Jsql;
$return = $db->connect(...);
if($return->success){ echo $return->response; }
else{ echo $return->debug_message; }
```

I know using a connect example here is trivial, but my question relates to the coding practice.

My main goal in this practice is to ensure I'm being consistent in how I am handling the return data from methods.

Notes: have mercy. This is my first question on here. :) I've been slowly self taught taking the normal route from dabbling in html years ago to moving toward procedural php and finally getting into OOP.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for [Programmers.se]. See [Is a "best practice" question off topic?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265928/2747593).

Comment: @ScottWeldon , noted; still learning the different sections on here. Thanks

Comment: @joegrom5 there are multiple questions that this would be a duplicate of on Programmers: I recommend searching over there for some good info.

Comment: @ScottWeldon when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Good point, thanks. I made a note of this so I won't forget to do it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a perfectly reasonable approach to me.

In terms of `being consistent in how I am handling the return data from methods` you could make the response class implement a Response *interface*, then you'll know that all types of response classes will adhere to the same rules so you can safely use it throughout your application:

```
interface MyResponseInterface
{
    public function getResponse();
    public function getDebugMessage();
    public function getSuccess();
    public function getMysqliConnection();
}

class JsqlResponse implements MyResponseInterface
{
    // ...
}
```

Then you know that whenever your object returns either a `JsqlResponse`, a `TimeResponse`, a `MemberResponse` etc, that they shall all implement your response interface, and as such your public getters will be available, e.g.:

```
/** @var MyResponseInterface $return */
$return = $db->connect(...);
if($return->getSuccess()) {
    echo $return->getResponse();
} else {
    echo $return->getDebugMessage();
}
```

**Note:** In my example of different kinds of responses you could return, I'd imagine (hypothetically) that Time and Member may not need a MySQL connection, so perhaps you could omit that from the `MyResponseInterface` and create a new interface for database connections, e.g. `MyDatabaseInterface`. Generic response classes would provide responses, debug messages and a success method.